# Enjoying movies that have elements of kufr is kufr?

Tags: kufr

Enjoying watching movies/anime that have elements of shirk/kufr is an act of disbelief? I know that just watching a movie/anime will not take a person out of Islam and I know that such questions have been asked here many times before. But I can't understand, if I like magic in some Harry Potter movie, do I automatically become a kafir? And one more question also connected with movies. Since Christmas is coming soon, they started to advertise all kinds of movies related to this subject on TV. I do not celebrate Christmas, because in my country few people celebrate it and in my opinion celebrating this "holiday" is an act of kufr, but will it be an act of kufr if I just watch some Christmas movie?

Answer (score 0):

It's not disbelief if you watch it but it's advised not to.